# Can i spawn a thread from a servlet?

Tags: multithreading, servlets

I would like to ask a basic question before i get on to my main question .

Lets say i am running a simple Java program, which spawns a thread in the main function. Will the thread continue to run when the main function completes?
Is there a concept of parent/child relationships between threads.

I have a servlet which takes a long while to process a request (5 mins). Can i spawn a background thread from the main servlet to handle the work & return soon. Would the background thread keep running even when the main servlet has finished processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is such thing as parent and child threads, but you don't have a lot of control on that. For example there's `InheritableThreadLocal`, where you can store variables for a thread hierarchy.
- you can spawn a new thread from a servlet. Prefer Java 5 executors framework
- if using servlet 3.0, take a look at its [asynchronous processing](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html?page=3) capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

When you want your application to exit even though you still have running threads, you **have** to mark your thread as a daemon thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(myRunnable);
t.setDaemon(true),
t.start();
```

This is especially important when you do that in an application server, otherwise the server cannot be shut down!

If you do that repeatedly you might want to consider a ThreadPool to make this more efficient